# Casting exception of LayoutParams

Tags: android

I have an activity which has a fragment in it (GFragmentMo class) which extends ListFragment (support.v4).
Since I've added the fragment, I get an exception every time this fragment is visible, and I'm pulling down the android drawer and then pulling it back up.

The fragment's root layout is LinearLayout and I'm not setting layout params anyware of any view.
I'm running on android 6.0 but it was reproduced also on 4.4.2.

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams
                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4221)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is the code I use to put this fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, new GFragmentMo(), null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This is the layout of the activity which holds the fragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/cContainer">
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
            android:visibility="gone"
            class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'd like to here any idea that can help solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045360/getting-classcastexception-when-trying-to-insert-relativelayout-dyanmically/10046252#10046252)? It might help.

Comment: I haven't changed the LayoutParams of the fragment. But thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest just changing the root LinearLayout to something else to see if the error persists, or if it changes.

Comment: By the exception, android expect LayoutParams of WindowManager, do you know how can I provide it? which layout to use? I'll try another one, just for trying...

Comment: @Vucko It didn't help, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that in a custom view that was in that fragment, I called by mistake `getRootView().setLayoutParams(...)` and that changed the layout params that I didn't mean to change.