# Relative Layout Params does not work properly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

i'm trying to code a chat screen which is similar to WhatsApp ,I mean, received messages aligned to left, sent messages aligned to right.

Here's the part of the code where i'm populating messageContainer with the messages.

```
List<Message> chatList = Database_IO.parseChat(user1, user2);

        for (Message m : chatList) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View message = li.inflate(R.layout.msgbubble, null);
            TextView messageText = message.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.messageText);
            messageText.setText(m.messageText);

            RelativeLayout messageContainer = findViewById(R.id.messageContainer);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)messageContainer.getLayoutParams();
            if (userID == m.sender.id) {
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            }
            if (userID == m.recipient.id) {
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            }
            messageContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
            messageContainer.addView(message);
        }
```

**msgbubble.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hey there, it's been a while, how are you? :)"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_chat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.messenger.ChatActivity">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/messageContainer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@id/msgPanel"
       android:orientation="vertical">

   </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/msgPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Gönder"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But  all I see is messages are on top of each other, at default (left) alignment.[image: Like this]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what if your `chatList` contains 1000 messages? would you add 1000 views to your `messageContainer`? are you aware of `ListView` / `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Add your mesage xml .  addView not gonna work . Why don't you use pre attached view ?

Comment: you need to use recycler view or listview to do this.it will just hold after screen limit

Comment: Oh, i didn't think about that. Do i need to replace Relative Layout with ListView or i need to put a ListView in my RelativeLayout? @pskink

Comment: @ADM XML's are added. Thanks for warning

Comment: yes, add `ListView` inside `RelativeLayout`

Comment: As pskink says, This will going to result in lagging in List view . So as a suggestion . Just put all your views in XMl and just change the gravity from adapter .  For better View Holder implementation use RecyclerView.

Comment: So can i use layoutParams with ListView? I'm kinda confused here since listView involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out what is my problem. My messagebubble's width was "match_parent" so i couldn't see the alignment.

I made it wrap_content and removed LayoutParams, they weren't working anyways.

this is my final code

```
for (Message m : chatList) {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View message = li.inflate(R.layout.msgbubble, null);

                TextView messageText = message.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.messageText);
                messageText.setText(m.messageText);
                LinearLayout msgBubble = message.findViewById(R.id.bubbleLayout);


                if (userID == m.sender.id) {
                    msgBubble.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    messageText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.inBlue));
                }
                if (userID == m.recipient.id) {
                    msgBubble.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    messageText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.outBlue));
                }
                messageContainer.addView(message);
            }
```

Thanks for any help, especially Tej for great and inspiring answer. Also thanks to others for pointing out possible performance-killer implementation!

Comment: I'm glad , you got your solution .

Answer (score 3):

You can use LinearLayout . something like this

```
List<Message> chatList = Database_IO.parseChat(user1, user2);

        for (Message m : chatList) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View message = li.inflate(R.layout.msgbubble, null);
            TextView messageText = message.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.messageText);
            messageText.setText(m.messageText);

            LinearLayout messageContainer = findViewById(R.id.messageContainer);
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
             params.weight = 1.0f;

            if (userID == m.sender.id) {
              params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                 messageContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
            if (userID == m.recipient.id) {
               params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
               messageContainer.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
            messageContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
            messageContainer.addView(message);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it caused me an error: "android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams"

Comment: @OnurDemiray may be in your xml you are still using RelativeLayout. check that

Comment: No, messageContainer is LinearLayout, i checked multiple times, tried re-writing the xml :(

Comment: After converting all RelativeLayouts in these two xml's, error transformed into this:

 "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams"

I have no framelayouts in my xml's and i'm pretty sure i'm defining layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: @OnurDemiray check your case with this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10046252/6880611)

Comment: I was exactly checking out that! It cleared the error, but alignment is still wrong. [here's how it looks now](https://imgur.com/a/h3kjq). Answer1 should be aligned to right since it's a sent message.

Comment: @OnurDemiray Is your `userID == m.sender.id` fulfilled?

Comment: Yes, i'm dropping some Logs as "aligned to right" and "aligned to left" and logcat perfectly shows code gets into if statements